# Is it possible to change text directly in the code

Tags: magento, text, filezilla

I would like to know if there is a way to change text in the code instead of using the admin panel? I have Filezilla installed and can access my site/files from there.

If I use the inspect element in any browser, I can see an HTML structure, but as I have understood there is no HTML document in Magento, right? So where do I go if I want to make a change to a text element on my site and I don't want to use the admin panel?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the text elements are handled by Magento's language translation system.

Quite often, you don't have to mess around hacking templates, just simply add a line to the translation CSV with the text string exactly as it appears, add a comma and then the new text string you want Magento to display.

For example, if you're working with US English, you can use the following file in your own custom template package as follows:

`app/design/frontend/default/your_package/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

Let's for example, change one of the window shade bar titles in the One Page Shopping Cart. Add a line to translate.csv as follows:

"Billing Information","Billing Address Information"

How this works, in the template the following line normally displays the title:

`<?php echo $this->__('Billing Address') ?>`

This code snippet `$this->__('Billing Address')` is a call to Magento's language translation system. It reads the `translate.csv` file finds `Billing Address` and changes it to `Billing Address Information` when it assembles the page html.

Lotta people out there have made changing text like this far harder than it has to be.

Hunting down the proper template, changing the text, finding the template got messed up, or trying to remember **after the fact** what was changed.

**VS.**

Changing a simple central file that contains all the text string translations... Often only by adding a new line to the file

Magento actually makes this very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! So magento stores all text in .csv? or just the stuff that needs to be translated? I'm making a search for .csv via Filezilla but I only get two languages (the site is translated to multiple languages). Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: This is not an answer, but should have been added as comment to @Fiasco-Labs' answer